How to Automatically Identify Column Headers in New Datasets Using Machine Learning?
I have a dataset with vehicle data that includes headers (example):

I receive new datasets with similar vehicle data but no column headers:

I need to create an algorithm to recognise and assign column headers to these new datasets based on the provided taxonomy from the dataset with headers. Here are some challenges:

Some values may not appear in the training dataset (e.g., "tesla" in the new file).
The sets of columns may not match entirely; the file without headers may have fewer or more columns.

Column types may vary between files (e.g., "id" as string vs. int).

The problem is not purely entity/attribute recognition.

Some variables are correlated (e.g., "fuel_type" vs. "engine_size"/"is_electric").

Preferably, the solution should use minimal heuristics and leverage machine learning to adapt to changing data.


Here’s what has been done so far:

Transposed the datasets to create a long-narrow dataframe with each row consisting of a column name and corresponding value:



Applied ~40 features on all values (e.g., word count, character length, is_text, is_bool, column aggregations like min, max, mean, entropy).

Trained a Random Forest classifier on this dataset (multiclass classification problem).

For the test dataset, ran the same preprocessing and feature creation, then classified each value.

Grouped predictions by unknown column and assigned known column names starting from the ones with the highest specificity (similar to tf-idf).


This solution has some issues:

Pivoting the dataset loses correlations within a single vehicle (e.g., "engine_size = 0" and "is_electric = T" are treated independently).

The solution assigns columns post-hoc, leading to potential overrepresentation of certain columns and lacking simultaneous optimization for all variables.


Have you encountered a similar problem? Do you know any tools or solutions that could help? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
